# Getting VBSCRIPT Error: "800a03f4"

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I have the following Function:

```
Function getNext10(num)
    pageLen = len(num)
    If pageLen = 1 Then
        next10 = 10
    ElseIf pageLen>1 Then
        pageRem = 10
        pageTen = right(num, 1)
        next10 = num + pageRem - pageTen
    End If
    getNext10 = next10
End Function
```

If I use that function I get the following Error:

> Microsoft VBScript compilation "800a03f4'
>
> 'If' expected
>
> /display/paging.asp, row 27
>
> End Function
>   ------^

What is wrong with that function?

Comment: It works just fine. The problem is elsewhere. How you call the function?

Comment: this is how i call the function: next10 = getNext10(CurrPage)

Comment: You already have `next10` in the function, you probably run into variable name conflict. Please add `Option Explicit` on top of your code, declare all variables using `Dim` and it would most likely solve your problems or at least give better error messages..

Comment: i did that already and i also declared the variables. I dont know where the problem coming from. Maybe i should post the whole code?

Comment: Yep try posting more code and we'll see.

Comment: Thanks for helf Wizard, but i found the Error on my own... -.-. In my Original version i had Else If instead of Elseif, that fixed the error

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Function getNext10(num)
    pageLen = len(num)
    If pageLen = 1 Then
        next10 = 10
    End If
    If pageLen>1 Then
        pageRem = 10
        pageTen = right(num, 1)
        next10 = num + pageRem - pageTen
    End If
    getNext10 = next10
End Function
```